# What does it mean for a B-tree index to be threaded?

Tags: data-structures, concurrency

I was reading about the concurrency control of the B-tree search trees, where it is stated that

> a search operation does not need any locks if nodes in the B-tree
>   index are **threaded at every level**.

I am confused about what it means for nodes in a tree or an index being threaded. I've heard of programs/subroutines being threaded (e.g. written in a thread-safe manner and so on). What does it mean for a node to be threaded?

I guess I am missing something obvious about this data-structure. Can someone help explain?

Comment: Not sure if it's the exact same concept, but there's a [Wikipedia article on threaded binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree). Maybe that helps.

Comment: @stakx Thanks! It seems I misunderstood the word "threaded" in this context.

Comment: Can you point us at the reference so we can see that quote in context? It seems odd that concurrent search would be affected by the existence of threads (as in the threaded binary tree sense).